# Group element with similar date into an array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need to merge datas from an array with PHP.

Supposing I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-03-26
            [person] => 120.00
            [color] => Black
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-03-26
            [person] => 120.00
            [color] => Yellow
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-03-27
            [person] => 120.00
            [color] => Red
        )
)
```

How I can merge datas with similar date to have something like this ?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [2018-03-26] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [person] => 120.00
                    [color] => Black
                )
                [1] => Array
                (
                    [person] => 120.00
                    [color] => Yellow
                )
            )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [2018-03-27] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [person] => 120.00
                    [color] => Red
                )
            )
        )
)
```

---

This is what I tried by reading some documentation over SO and Google:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($initialArray as $item) {
    if (!empty($newArray[$item['date']])) {
        $currentValue = $newArray[$item['date']];
        $newArray[$item['date']]['person'] = $item['person'];
        $newArray[$item['date']]['color'] = $item['color'];
    } else {
        $newArray[$item['date']] = $item;
    }
}
```

What I missing here please ?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the point of the extra array layer around the arrays with the date keys? Is that necessary? Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution:

```
$return = array();
foreach($datas as $val) {
    if (!isset($return[$val['date']])) {
        $return[$val['date']] = array();
    }
    $return[$val['date']][] = $val;
}
```

Comment: Does not match with the expected output of your question.